# How to count the total number of vowels in a string

Tags: python

Hi is there a better way of writing this code instead of writing the repetitive multiple if statements? I'm trying to find a better way of writing this code. Basically I want to count up the the total number of matching letters in the given string s.

```
s = 'abcdbobbobbegkhl'
count = 0
for letter in s:
    if letter == 'a':
        count += 1
    if letter == 'e':
        count += 1
    if letter == 'i':
        count += 1
    if letter == 'o':
        count += 1
    if letter == 'u':
        count += 1
print('Number of vowels: ' + str(count))
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
s = 'abcdbobbobbegkhl'
count = len([i for i in s if i in 'aeiou'])
print('Number of vowels: ' + str(count))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
s = 'abcdbobbobbegkhl'
count = 0
for letter in s:
    if letter in 'aeiou':
        count += 1
print('Number of vowels: ' + str(count))
```

Or a one-liner:

```
count = sum(l in 'aeiou' for l in s)
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can use the == operator for this?

Comment: @Tim yes you could use the `or` keyword

Comment: I guess I'm having diffculty wrapping my head around the concept or understanding of a if statement inside a for loop in this example.  Can you explain this whole idea of this algorithm in detail?  For example if we already establish the for loop: for letter in s, then why is it follow by the statement: if letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']?  Can't we establish another variable outside of the for loop, let's call it vowel = 'aeiou', follow by a for loop: for letter in s, then inside the for loop set vowel == s, then increment with a counter count += 1.  Is this logic right?

Comment: How would I write this code if I want to use the operator == ?

Comment: @Tim we go through every letter that is in `s`. Then we test it to see if it is also inside the string 'aeiou'. In other words, `if letter == 'a' or letter == 'e' or letter == 'i' or letter =='o' or letter == 'u'`. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes that makes sense now.  Thank you for clarifying the concepts for me mate!

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'abcdbobbobbegkhl'
count = 0
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

for letter in s:
    if letter in vowels:
        count += 1

print('Number of vowels: ' + str(count))
```

Comment: So in this example is it correct to think of the if statement inside of this for-loop, as " iterate through all letters in the variable string s", then inside the string s look for or match the letters strings in s with the letter string in variable vowel?

Comment: The for loop iterates over every character in the string ```s``` using a variable ```letter```. The if statement checks each ```letter``` to see if it is contained in the list ```vowels``` and increments the ```count``` if it is a vowel. Does that help?

Comment: Try giving this a read: [Python Iterators](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/iterator)

Answer (score 1):

Can be written in many ways. One of them is like :

```
for letter in s:
    if letter in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        count = count+1
print('Number of vowels: ' + str(count))
```

Comment: I guess I'm having diffculty wrapping my head around the concept or understanding of a if statement inside a for loop in this example.  Can you explain this whole idea of this algorithm in detail?  For example if we already establish the for loop: for letter in s, then why is it follow by the statement: if letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']?  Can't we establish another variable outside of the for loop, let's call it vowel = 'aeiou', follow by a for loop: for letter in s, then inside the for loop set vowel == s, then increment with a counter count += 1.  Is this logic right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, which may be nice:

```
s = 'abcdbobbobbegkhl'

vowels = 'aeiou'
count= 0

for vowel in vowels:
    count += s.count(vowel)

print('Number of vowels: ' + str(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dict as the vocals set, you made direct access to vocals instead of to find in a list.

```py
vocals = {'a':1,'e':1,'i':1,'o':1,'u':1}
s = "aeioutr"
count = 0
for letter in s:
  try:
    count+=vocals[letter]
  except KeyError:
    print(f"{letter} is not a vocal")
print(count) #5
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, not exactly what was asked for, but might be useful anyway *if the OP's goal is to count letter frequencies*.  This is using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to keep track of letter counts.

```
from collections import Counter

s = "I am a foobar and I have many vowels"

vowels = "aeiou"

vowels += vowels.upper()

counter = Counter(s)

sum_ = 0
for ch in vowels:
    sum_ += counter[ch]

print(f"Number of vowels:{sum_}")
```

Output:

```
Number of vowels:13
```